# как правильно импортировать библиотеку в cx_freeze

Tags: python, exe, cx-freeze

хотел конвертировать свой python файл в exe с помощью cx_freeze и при составлении setup файла возник один вопрос:

У меня есть мой python файл в котором я использую такие библиотеки:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import time
import telebot
```

и у меня есть setup файл в котором я импортирую эти библиотеки:

```
includes = ['requests', 'bs4', 'os', 'time', 'telebot']

zip_include_packages = [ 'requests', 'bs4', 'os', 'time', 'telebot' ]
```

Вопрос касается конкретно библиотеки bs4. Как мне правильно ее передать в cx_freeze?
Заранее спасибо

Comment: `beautifulsoup4`?

Comment: @МихаилМуругов да

Comment: просто я обращаюсь в python файле к ней как просто BS, может для этого есть какие специальные методы в cx_freeze

Comment: Вопрос был: "Как передать bs4". Я с cx_freeze не знаком, но, судя по тому, как Вы туда прокидываете другие либы, мне показалось, что они передаются туда по имени с pypi. bs4 на pypi называется beautifulsoup4.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов попробовал сделать так в консоле выдает такое 
ImportError: No module named 'beautifulsoup4'
Просто мне кажется проблема в том, что я объявляю эту библиотеку по другому (from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS) из за этого есть какой то конфликт в программе

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается просто забыл добавить файл в директорию с exe шником,
Плохо что нельзя дебажить код в этой программке, а то так в слепую очень сложно разбираться